# Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException when resolving viewModelType in AppContainer

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin, mvvm, dependency-injection

I'm trying to bind my Views to my ViewModels using a `ViewModelLocator` (the one provided by Microsoft) which uses the custom `AppContainer` class to Resolve the modelType of the dynamically obtained ViewModel. However, whenever this Resolve function is called, it throws a "`Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException`".

Full error:

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException
>     Message=An exception was thrown while activating Kahood3.ViewModels.LandingsPageViewModel -> Kahood3.Services.NavigationService.
>     Source=Autofac
>     StackTrace:
>     at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] parameters, System.Object& decoratorTarget) [0x00060] in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:135 
>     at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup+<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<Execute>b__0 () [0x00000] in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:85 
>     at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare (System.Guid id, System.Func`1[TResult] creator) [0x00045] in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Lifetime\LifetimeScope.cs:312 
>     at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute () [0x0003e] in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:83 
>     at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance (Autofac.Core.ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistration registration, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] parameters) [0x00071] in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Resolving\ResolveOperation.cs:131 
>     at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ResolveComponent (Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistration registration, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] parameters) [0x00000] in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Resolving\ResolveOperation.cs:69 
>     at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute (Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistration registration, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] parameters) [0x00016] in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Resolving\ResolveOperation.cs:93 
>     at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent (Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistration registration, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] parameters) [0x00041] in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Lifetime\LifetimeScope.cs:282 
>     at Autofac.Core.Container.ResolveComponent (Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistration registration, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] parameters) [0x00000] in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Container.cs:170 
>     at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService (Autofac.IComponentContext context, Autofac.Core.Service service, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] parameters, System.Object& instance) [0x00023] in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\ResolutionExtensions.cs:1041 
>     at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService (Autofac.IComponentContext context, Autofac.Core.Service service, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] parameters) [0x00030] in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\ResolutionExtensions.cs:877 
>     at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve (Autofac.IComponentContext context, System.Type serviceType, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] parameters) [0x00000] in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\ResolutionExtensions.cs:347 
>     at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve (Autofac.IComponentContext context, System.Type serviceType) [0x00000] in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\ResolutionExtensions.cs:331 
>     at Kahood3.Util.AppContainer.Resolve (System.Type typeName) [0x00001] in C:...\Kahood3\Kahood3\Kahood3\Util\AppContainer.cs:29 
>     at Kahood3.Util.ViewModelLocator.OnAutoWireViewModelChanged (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject bindable, System.Object oldValue, System.Object newValue) [0x000b8] in C:...\Util\ViewModelLocator.cs:56 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueActual (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+BindablePropertyContext context, System.Object value, System.Boolean currentlyApplying, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, System.Boolean silent) [0x00120] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:445 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueCore (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes) [0x00173] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:379 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, System.Boolean fromStyle, System.Boolean checkAccess) [0x00042] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:316 
>     at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:293 
>     at Kahood3.Views.LandingsPageView.InitializeComponent () [0x00023] in C:\Users...\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\Views\LandingsPageView.xaml.g.cs:26 
>     at Kahood3.Views.LandingsPageView..ctor () [0x00008] in C:\Users...\Views\LandingsPageView.xaml.cs:20 
>     at Kahood3.App..ctor () [0x0001d] in C:\Users...\App.xaml.cs:19 
>     at Kahood3.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x0002f] in C:\Users...\Kahood3.Android\MainActivity.cs:24 
>     at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in :0 
>     at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.8(intptr,intptr,intptr)

I tried debugging the different variables without any progress. While checking the value of the viewModelType, it shows the correct ViewModel.

`ViewModelLocator` file

```
private static void OnAutoWireViewModelChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Inside OnAutoWireViewModelChanged");

    if (!(bindable is Element view))
    {
        return;
    }

    var viewType = view.GetType();
    if (viewType.FullName != null)
    {
        var viewName = viewType.FullName.Replace(".Views.", ".ViewModels.");
        var viewAssemblyName = viewType.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName;
        var viewModelName = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}Model, {1}", viewName, viewAssemblyName);
        //var viewModelName = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}Model", viewName);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(" viewModelName: " + viewModelName);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(" viewAssemblyName: " + viewAssemblyName);

        var viewModelType = Type.GetType(viewModelName);
        if (viewModelType == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        var viewModel = AppContainer.Resolve(viewModelType); //Resolve the viewModelType
        view.BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

Inside the `AppContainer`

```
public static object Resolve(Type typeName)
{
    return _container.Resolve(typeName); //Throws the error here
}
```

View XAML file:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Kahood3.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="Kahood3.Views.LandingsPageView"
         xmlns:utility="clr-namespace:Kahood3.Util"
         utility:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">


    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
           FontSize="Large"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="Center">
        </Label>
        <Button x:Name="startButton" Text="Start!" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference startButton}, Path=BindingContext.Start_Quiz}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I'm a little confusing why are you `calling _container.Resolve` in method Resolve inside the class AppContainer? Is this the same method? If not, what is _container.Resolve?

Comment: Please post the full exception details. This means adding information about the exception and *all* its inner exceptions, their messages, and their stack traces.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT In the resolve method the IContainer's Resolve method is called which resolves the type of the provided object name. In my case, the passed value is Kahood3.ViewModels.LandingsPageViewModel which should then return an instance of the LandingsPageViewModel (if i'm not mistaking)

Comment: @Steven I have added the full exception. Does this make the problem more clear?

Comment: Look at your NavigationService constructor. Are you calling any methods in the NavigationService constructor